# jTable paint() leads to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, swing, jtable, heap-memory

I am trying to build jTable in which I have a heavy (not very heavy) task of painting each cell of jTable. But I'm not painting very frequently (painting/updating each cell very rarely). After implementing jTable I encountered `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I figured out that it is due to the call to `paint(Graphics g, JComponent c)` each microsecond. I don't wish to call this method all the time only in the case when table gets updated/modified. Is there any way to solve this problem?

**Edit:**

I have not called paint manually. The table has a manually created UI which is set using the `setUI` method. I have used this UI to create cells that can span multiple rows or columns (i.e. to merge few cells together).

`setUI(new MultiSpanCellTableUI());`

The class `MultiSpanCellTableUI` implements a `paint()` method which is getting called every second.

```
public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Rectangle oldClipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
    Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(oldClipBounds);
    int tableWidth = table.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth();
    clipBounds.width = Math.min(clipBounds.width, tableWidth);
    g.setClip(clipBounds);

    int firstIndex = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(0, clipBounds.y));
    int lastIndex = table.getRowCount() - 1;

    Rectangle rowRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tableWidth,
            table.getRowHeight() + table.getRowMargin());
    rowRect.y = firstIndex * rowRect.height;

    for (int index = firstIndex; index <= lastIndex; index++) {
        if (rowRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
            paintRow(g, index);
        }
        rowRect.y += rowRect.height;
    }
    g.setClip(oldClipBounds);
}

private void paintRow(Graphics g, int row) {    
    System.out.println("paintRow called");

    Rectangle rect = g.getClipBounds();
    boolean drawn = false;

    AttributiveCellTableModel tableModel = (AttributiveCellTableModel) table
            .getModel();
    CellSpan cellAtt = (CellSpan) tableModel.getCellAttribute();
    int numColumns = table.getColumnCount();

    for (int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
        Rectangle cellRect = table.getCellRect(row, column, true);
        int cellRow, cellColumn;
        if (cellAtt.isVisible(row, column)) {
            cellRow = row;
            cellColumn = column;
        } else {
            cellRow = row + cellAtt.getSpan(row, column)[CellSpan.ROW];
            cellColumn = column
                    + cellAtt.getSpan(row, column)[CellSpan.COLUMN];
        }
        if (cellRect.intersects(rect)) {
            drawn = true;
            System.out.println("paintCell called!");
            paintCell(g, cellRect, cellRow, cellColumn);
        } else {
            if (drawn)
                break;
        }
    }

}

private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int row, int column) {
    int spacingHeight = table.getRowMargin();
    int spacingWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();

    Color c = g.getColor();
    g.setColor(table.getGridColor());
    g.drawRect(cellRect.x, cellRect.y, cellRect.width - 1,
            cellRect.height - 1);
    g.setColor(c);

    cellRect.setBounds(cellRect.x + spacingWidth / 2, cellRect.y
            + spacingHeight / 2, cellRect.width - spacingWidth,
            cellRect.height - spacingHeight);

    if (table.isEditing() && table.getEditingRow() == row
            && table.getEditingColumn() == column) {
        Component component = table.getEditorComponent();
        component.setBounds(cellRect);
        component.validate();
    } else {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        Component component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if (component.getParent() == null) {
            rendererPane.add(component);
        }
        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, table, cellRect.x,
                cellRect.y, cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }
}
```

Since it is called every second, after a while the `OutOfMemoryError` occurs. I only need to repaint the cells when I update something in the cell and that information I can obtain easily. But how can I limit the calls to `paint()` based on that information?

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org). Also, you should never explicitly invoke `paint`, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: @Крысa I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: if I tried example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiSpanCellTableExample.htm, then I got lots of another exceptions, never OME

Answer (score 2):

not sure why do you needed

1) painting by `paint()`, please for which type of Components in the `JTable's Cel`l, if is there some JComponent the you have to override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`

2) not good design to perform custom painting in the larger `JTable`

3) you have to look at `Renderer`, better would be `prepareRenderer` if you painting by using some Color

4) `JTable` by default returns `JLabel`, there you can set `Icon` instaead of prerform some custom painting

5) maybe help you with `JTable's` performance [Christmas Tree Applications](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/)

Answer (score 1):

With no code posted above, I assume you are forcing a `paint()` on the `JTable` component. 
There should not be a need to call `paint()` on the `JTable` object. To customize cell painting, use a `TableCellRenderer` instead.

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
        if (isSelected) {
            // Is cell selected?
        }
        if (hasFocus) {
            // Does this cell have the focus
        }
        // Configure the component with the specified value, here we are using JLabel
        setText(value.toString());
        // Set tool tip if desired
        setToolTipText((String)value);
        // Since the renderer is a component, return itself
        return this;
    }
}
```